# Invalid Datatype when passing collection into function

Tags: oracle, plsql

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE test_package
IS
  TYPE IDTable IS TABLE OF test_table.id%TYPE;

  TYPE RowIDTable IS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(500);

  FUNCTION delete_rows (row_ids IN RowIDTable) RETURN IDTable;
END test_package;
/

CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY test_package
IS
  FUNCTION delete_rows (row_ids IN RowIDTable) RETURN IDTable
  IS
    ids IDTable;
  BEGIN
    DELETE FROM test_table
    WHERE ROWIDTONCHAR(rowid) IN (SELECT * FROM TABLE(row_ids))
    RETURNING id BULK COLLECT INTO ids;

    COMMIT;

    RETURN ids;
  END;
END test_package;
/
```

I keep getting `ORA-00902: invalid datatype` when using the above function. What am I doing wrong?

The error is pointing to the DELETE statement.

Comment: I don’t see an error running your code in 12cR2. What version are you using?

Comment: Hi I'm pretty sure it's 12c but I don't know if it's 12cR2. Could you paste the code that you use to call my function?

Comment: I narrowed down the error to this part `(SELECT * FROM TABLE(row_ids))`. The function works if I replace it with a regular list of stringified rowids. But I don't know why the original code does not work! It seems like it should.

Comment: Yeah, I thought you were reporting a compilation error (despite ‘using’); I get a runtime error too.

Comment: Oh I see. at least I'm not the only one. I thought I was going crazy.

Comment: Be aware, unless the records are locked the `ROWID` may change while your application is running.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit do the rowids change when the data is updated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the problem is the type of collection you’re using. in that it’s a package-level PL/SQL collection type.

[The ruby-plsql documentation](https://github.com/rsim/ruby-plsql/blob/master/README.md) says it supports PL/SQL records, but the table and varray types don’t refer to PL/SQL - suggesting they have to be SQL (i.e. schema-level) user-defined types.

Even without Ruby in the picture, the invalid-datatype error is thrown at runtime, when the same package-defined types are used consistently. Prior to 12c you couldn’t use a PL/SQL collection in a SQL statement at all, and it still doesn’t seem to work in this scenario.

Your code works if you change from the the PL/SQL type to a schema-level type, in this example a built-in varray type:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE test_package
IS
  TYPE IDTable IS TABLE OF test_table.id%TYPE;

  --TYPE RowIDTable IS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(500); —- not used now

  FUNCTION delete_rows (row_ids IN sys.odcivarchar2list) RETURN IDTable;
END test_package;
/

CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY test_package
IS
  FUNCTION delete_rows (row_ids IN sys.odcivarchar2list) RETURN IDTable
  IS
    ids IDTable;
  BEGIN
    DELETE FROM test_table
    WHERE ROWIDTONCHAR(rowid) IN (SELECT * FROM TABLE(row_ids))
    RETURNING id BULK COLLECT INTO ids;

    COMMIT;

    RETURN ids;
  END;
END test_package;
/
```

which you can test with anonymous block:

```
declare
  ids test_package.idtable;
begin
  ids := test_package.delete_rows(sys.odcivarchar2list('ROWID1', 'ROWID2'));
end;
/
```

It would be more efficient to *not* convert every rowid in the table, so you can do this instead:

```
WHERE rowid IN (SELECT CHARTOROWID(column_value) FROM TABLE(row_ids))
```

but bear in mind that rowids are not always immutable - hopefully the references you are passing in are recent enough to always still be valid. Otherwise, work with primary keys rather than rowids.

I don’t know Ruby so not entirely sure how that translates; again from the docs it looks like:

```
plsql.test_package.delete_rows(['ROWID1','ROWID2'])
```

... but not sure how it’ll handle the returned (PL/SQL) table type. That may need to be a schema-level table type too. (And you can probably create types as either varrays or nested tables if you want to make your own, which is probably a good idea.)

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use `TABLE OF ROWID` instead of `TABLE OF VARCHAR2(500)` on RowIDTable?

Like so:

```
TYPE RowIDTable IS TABLE OF ROWID;
```

Then you wouldn't have to cast ROWID:

```
DELETE FROM test_table tbl
WHERE tbl.rowid IN (SELECT column_value FROM TABLE(row_ids))
RETURNING id BULK COLLECT INTO ids;
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi Thanks for responding. The function is to be consumed in a ruby app. I have another function that returns a bunch of rowids that it processed but they get turned into string when arriving in ruby. Once I do my processing in ruby I'm supposed to call the function in question and delete the rows that match the rowids. That's why I'm having to cast.


The library that I'm using is the ruby-plsql gem which  allows me to pass a regular ruby array which converts into the plsql collection.

Comment: You can also write `where tbl.rowid member of row_ids `